# How to ensure the abline / identity line is centered 1:1 in each subplot with individual axis limits in Matplotlib? [edited] [solved]

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, scatter-plot, subplot

I have a 2x2 subplot grid, where each subplot contains a scatter plot with different data points. I'm trying to draw a common abline (slope=1, intercept=0) in each subplot to visualize the relationship between the data points. However, due to varying data ranges in each subplot, the abline does not appear centered 1:1 in all subplots.

I want to ensure that the abline is centered 1:1 in each subplot while maintaining individual axis limits for each plot based on the data points within that specific subplot. In other words, I want the abline to pass through the center of each subplot's data points without distorting the data.

Could someone please guide me on how to achieve the correct centering of the abline in each subplot while keeping individual axis limits based on the data points within that subplot?

Thats the code:

```
timesteps = [185, 159, 53, 2]

def abline(ax, slope, intercept):
    """Plot a line from slope and intercept"""
    x_vals = np.array(ax.get_xlim())
    y_vals = intercept + slope * x_vals
    ax.plot(x_vals, y_vals, 'r--')

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 8))

for i, timestep in enumerate(timesteps):
    mask = np.where(nan_mask[timestep, :, :] == 0)
    data_tmwm_values = data_tmwm[timestep, :, :][mask]
    ds_plot_values = ds_og_red[timestep, :, :][mask]

    row = i // 2  # Integer division to get the row index
    col = i % 2  # Modulo operation to get the column index
    
    ax = axs[row, col]
    ax.scatter(data_tmwm_values, ds_plot_values, s=20)
    ax.set_xlabel('TMWM')
    ax.set_ylabel('Original')
    ax.set_title(f'Scatter Plot (Timestep: {timestep})')

    correlation_matrix = np.corrcoef(data_tmwm_values, ds_plot_values)
    r_value = correlation_matrix[0, 1]

    r_squared = r_value ** 2
    abline(ax, 1, 0)
    ax.text(0.05, 0.95, f"R\u00b2 value: {r_squared:.3f}", transform=ax.transAxes, ha='left', va='top')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

And thats the image:

[image]

I have already tried using the get_xlim() and get_ylim() functions to set the axis limits for each subplot, but it doesn't result in a proper centering of the abline.

Comment: In many cultures they read left to right, top to bottom, and they look at time from the beginning to the end. Your arrangement of subplots could seem strange to them. Coming to your question, **you draw a red line that is independent of your data** aka points in each scatter plot, and **you want that the barycenter of the points belongs to the line**, correct? Could you please clarify ([edit]) what you _really_ want?

Comment: The Timestep thing is ordered like it is because these are just timestep examples which work from good to bad (top left to bottom right). But I will do that better in the future, thanks for mentioning it.
some3128 gave me the answer with doing an identy line. So this is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want an identity line, but you are attempting a linear fit instead. A linear fit might still be useful for you since you calculate various correlation metrics and overlay R2.

The example below shows how to add a linear fit as well as an identity (y=x) line.

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

timesteps = [185, 159, 53, 2]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 8))

for timestep, ax in zip(timesteps, axs.flatten()):
    #Synthetic data
    data_tmwm_values = np.random.randn(200) * 10 + timestep / 2
    ds_plot_values = np.random.randn(200) * 20 + timestep / 2

    ax.scatter(data_tmwm_values, ds_plot_values, s=20)
    ax.set_xlabel('TMWM')
    ax.set_ylabel('Original')
    ax.set_title(f'Scatter Plot (Timestep: {timestep})')

    correlation_matrix = np.corrcoef(data_tmwm_values, ds_plot_values)
    r_value = correlation_matrix[0, 1]
    r_squared = r_value ** 2
    ax.text(0.05, 0.95, f"R\u00b2 value: {r_squared:.3f}", transform=ax.transAxes, ha='left', va='top')
    
    #Fit a straight line
    slope, intercept = np.polyfit(data_tmwm_values, ds_plot_values, deg=1)
    #Add the line to the plot, preserving the x and y ranges of the data
    x_low, x_high, y_low, y_high = ax.axis() #Get axis limits
    ax.plot([x_low, x_high], slope * np.array([x_low, x_high]) + intercept, 'r--', label='linear fit of data')
    
    #add identity line, in case that is what you wanted
    lim_low = min(x_low, y_low)
    lim_high = max(x_high, y_high)
    ax.plot([lim_low, lim_high], [lim_low, lim_high], '-k', linewidth=2, label='y=x identity line')
    
    #add legend for a plot, to clarify what the lines represent
    if ax is axs[0, 1]: ax.legend(loc='upper right') 
    
    #optional - clip limits to remove some padding
    ax.axis([lim_low, lim_high, lim_low, lim_high])
    
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Identy Line is what I need. I just didnt know how it is named and coming from R this was not trivial. thanks for sharing! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it was helpful.